# Visual Studio Python reccomendations from module are incomplete

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I followed a tutorial for websockets in python and stumbled across the issue that pylance does not reccomend me the fuctions related to the class that I have imported from a module:

My Editor:

[image]

The Tutorial:

[image]

The Code Itself runs without any issue, so the Import seems to work, but I dont recieve the reccomendations in vs code. What is the reason for this or where could i debug something like this?

Comment: Did you try typing in `conn`? You might have other suggestions that are outranking the ones you want

Comment: Yes but but `imports` and `version` are the only two functions/variables that show up aside the `__xxx__` variables. If i enter `conn` the reccomendation does not show up at all..

Comment: I see. Go into settings and search `editor.suggest.showClasses` and make sure it's turned on.

Comment: That option is enabled. I should have added the information that I only experience this on the `websockets` module working with other modules I don't experience those issues. Regardless if the other modules are default ones or not.

Comment: I'm looking at [`websockets`'s `__init__.py`](//github.com/aaugustin/websockets/blob/main/src/websockets/__init__.py), and `imports` and `version` are the only two modules actually imported from. All the other names are specified under `__all__` and imported lazily. But in [earlier versions](//github.com/aaugustin/websockets/blob/8.0/src/websockets/__init__.py), everything was actually imported. So maybe the tutorial is based on an older version, and Pylance can't do suggestions based on the new structure. I can't confirm myself cause I'm using Jedi and I don't have `websockets` installed.

Comment: I wrote an Answer to the issue, mentioning the `lazily` imports lead me to take a look inside the module and a little search about the function lazy imports actually serve.

It obviously makes sense now why its used and why I dont revice the preview seen inside the tutorial with the current version. 
Importing mentioned scripts listed inside the aliasses for the lazily import serves as a good workarround (more on that inside my answer).
Thanks, I learned something new about python and modules inside of it today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [wjandrea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4518341/wjandrea) I found some thing I personally did not stumble acros before.

So a classic mistake happened to me when following a tutorial, I work on newer versions than the 1.5 year old video... Unfortunately the part talking about versions was in a nother part...

Long story short, in the mean time a bigger change for the websockets module appeared since the used functions are now imported lazily. Wich makes sense to reduce startup time incase you'll run a websocket server with the module.
[Little info about lazy imports](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2022/06/15/python-lazy-imports-with-cinder/)
 (for me it was the first time i heard about this intelligent feature)

**Incase anybody else stumbles across this im currently on Python 3.10.7 and I am talking about websockets 10.3!**

Back to the issue.
Pylance obviously can't make any reccomendations since the functions like `websockets.connect(uri, ...)` are just loaded if they are used in the runtime by the default `websockets` module so tools for code reccomendations inside the editor dont not know they are there..

I took a glance inside the module and through the indirect hint from [wjandrea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4518341/wjandrea) about the lazy imports inside `__init__.py` the listed dictionary made much more sense now! Based on this I could backtrack the Python scripts I need for my functions or rather Pylance needs to create those handy reccomendations for me inside vs code (or any other ide).

For now I just manually imported the desired script so I have a bit more guidance while writing and since startuptime in my current project is not crutial I let the manual imports exist or i´ll just change out the import variations based on the cirumstance if I am currently developing or if the code goes into production.